# How can I implement programmable javascript file selection within a HTML source file in conjunction with the use of the <form> <option> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to programming in HTML/CSS/Javascript. I've been working on JS code examples for implementing different JS datatypes [Arrays, Sets, BST, Queues, Stacks, Graphs (BFS)]. I have my code examples for each datatype implementation currently working in separate .js files which I am linking in for execution in one .html file. I have been trying to find a way to implement a programmable selection of any one of my datatype .js files from within the .html file  tag based on the user selecting the choice specified in a   tag list. So far, I have not been able to figure out a way or find an example of how to implement a user-programmable selection of multiple .js files from within a .html file. Is this even possible using basic HTML/CSS/Javascript files or would I need to implement this programmability using something like JQuery? Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Rob

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<select>` and `<option>` elements. At `change` event of `<select>` element, perform the task associated with the `.value` of `<select>` element, which corresponds to the `.value` of the `<option>` selected by user.

HTML

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
onload = function() {
  const select = document.querySelector("select");
  select.onchange = function(event) {
    // do stuff with `select.value`
  }
}
```

Comment: You then have to load the corresponding javascript files by injecting `<script>` tags into the document's `<head>`.